# new to NGINX how do I use htaccess equivalent?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, debian, http-status-code-404

I've used an online converter trying to turn my htaccess for pyrocms into something readable by nginx as I keep getting 404 errors.

The converter has given me this:

```
    # nginx configuration
location ~ 403 {
rewrite ^(.*)$ ^/.*/(system/cms/cache|system/codeigniter|system/cms/config|system/cms/logs|\.git|\.hg).*$ redirect;
}
location / {
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 break;
}
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 break;
}
```

Where do I need to add this into my filesystem?
Debian OS

Answer (score 1):

On debian your nginx server configuration files are located in /etc/nginx/sites-available/
By default you should have a /etc/nginx/sites-available/default corresponding to the default configuration.
You should read nginx documentation : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html